# Finding cause of "Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width is not available on iOS versions prior to 8.0"

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode6, xcode6.1

I know the reason of this warning and how to solve it: to give a preferred width to the label.

The problem is that, when I click that warning, I don't see any label/view/viewcontroller selected. The storyboard opens and that's it. There are many view controllers with many views in my storyboard. How can I find out which label is causing the problem without iterating through all the view controllers manually? When I click the warning, I expect it to take me to the view causing the warning, but it just opens the storyboard.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is one way to find the specific label that is causing this warning:

1. Right click on the warning and choose "Reveal in Log"
2. The warning in the log will be highlighted.  Copy the interface builder object ID for this label (it looks like xxx-xx-xxx).
3. Paste this in the Find Navigator.  When you click on this result it will open the interface builder with the offending label selected.

Comment: While it's not something ideal and non-intuitive, I think it's the only way to do this currently. Thanks.

Comment: 'Reveal in Log' doesn't seem to do anything in Xcode 6.2 (6C131e), at least in this .xcworkspace I'm working with. :(

Comment: @taber Yeah, it's not doing anything for me either in 6.2

Comment: If you already fixed the warning, you may need to clean the project to make it disappear.

Answer (score 12):

Running XCODE 6.1, I found the easiest way to do find the error was through the Report Navigator.

1. `View` -> `Navigators` -> `Show Report Navigator` or simply press `⌘-8`
2. Click on the build in the left pane.
3. Click the details icon next to the warning.

[image]

4. Find the object id in the warning description.

[image]

5. Go to the file and search `⌘-f` for the object id.

[image]

6. Fix the issue. [Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width is not available on iOS versions prior to 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398312/automatic-preferred-max-layout-width-is-not-available-on-ios-versions-prior-to-8)

Answer (score 2):

As said in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398312/automatic-preferred-max-layout-width-is-not-available-on-ios-versions-prior-to-8), you can also use this regex 
**<label(?!.*preferredMaxLayoutWidth)** in storyboard source to find all labels that do not have a preferredMaxLayoutWidth setted. Then correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Answer of @Don Eichenseer is great. But for those who want to solve it:
I've got the same problem before. The issue was because of a `UILabel` which its `Lines` property (in Attributes inspector) was more than `1`. When you have found the related `UILabel`, set it Lines to `1`.

Comment: This is not a solution. What if the label is required to be a multline.

Comment: Yeah this is not an absolute solution. It's for the labels that are not required to be multiline.

Answer (score 2):

just remove number of line from label and set it programmatically

```
[label setNumberOfLines:2];
```

Comment: It's NOT a solution, just a workaround for the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Is that the warning from a collection view? If so I'd guess it's a cell and a label with number of lines set to zero.

Comment: nope, it was a regular label. I've found it (there were multiple of them). But it is counter-productive to find out the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in an existing project developed in 7.1 without autolayouts.
Once I migrated the app to iOS8 and changed in the project file the version to 8.0, for some reason I got that warning in the Xib's where I used UILabel's with multiple lines.

in order to correct the problem, select the file inspector for the Xib and check the version it Builds for, in my case it was still for iOS7

[image]

you should change the Build for to the relevant version

[image]

and the warning will disappear as it did in my case :-)

Comment: but what if I also need to support pre-iOS 8?

Comment: well, you could support auto layouts in iOS7, as I mention, in my case, once I migrated to iOS8, the Xib's remained in iOS7 (didn't migrate) and I got the warning about the "Automatic Preferred  Max Layout Width". Once I changed in the File Inspector the Build for to iOS8 (same as in the project), the warning disappeared. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I must switch to XCode 6.2 --> click on warning icon at top right of the main XCode area --> choose the warning --> it shows exactly the item that cause the warning.
[image]