# My ios app is not running in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have used Autolayout in storyboard and it was working fine in ios7 before a week. but I have altered some constraints before 2 days after that app is not running in iOS7. I am getting following warning in storyboard.

```
"Automatic preferred max layout width is not available on ios versions prior to 8.0"
```

in xcode console window I am getting following error,

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
 reason: 'Unable to create description in descriptionForLayoutAttribute_layoutItem_coefficient. 
Something is nil'"
```

Could anyone please help me to find the solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width is not available on iOS versions prior to 8.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398312/automatic-preferred-max-layout-width-is-not-available-on-ios-versions-prior-to-8)

Comment: @Sakthi are you setting constraints with "constraint with margin" as tick you cannot run in ios7