# AutoLayout constraints leadin & tailing acts different on iOS7 & iOS8

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I have faced with strange behaviour. I've started my project with terget version of iOS as 8.4. Then after setting AutoLayout I've changed it to 7.0. This issue occure only in one view. In all views I use "Relative to margin".

This is how it looks like

[image]

This is UILabel with constraints leading, tailing setted to 0 Relative to superview margin

[image]

That how looks like views hierarchy.

[image]

Quick look on preview. All seams to be fine.

[image]

On iOS 8 looks great.

[image]

Poof, on iOS 7 constraints behave like (base value) - 8. I've checked it by changing value to 0,8 and 16. I didn't change the constraints programmatically. It seams like only leading and tailing constraints acts this way.

Also I've faced with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398312/automatic-preferred-max-layout-width-is-not-available-on-ios-versions-prior-to-8) issue in this view and solve it by setting width to 0.

I have no idea what I could do wrong.

## Update

I try to change to uncheck "Relative to Margin". But with no succes. What's more this is checked in other views and there isn't such issue.

Comment: Instead of applying this weird effect to the labels, why don't you change the text if this information ins sensitive? It makes it really hard to tell the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: -.- true, one second I just change bacground color for those views

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr I hope that is more readable?

Comment: I would still prefer some Lorem Ipsum, but it's better nonetheless.

Comment: Those data are from private API so there is no way I could make them like you wrote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was "Relative to margin" after all. But instead of unchecking this option in `UILabel` constraints. I've to did it in `UITableView` and it works.