# Why JSQMessages prints unrecognized selector sent to instance error?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, messenger, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

When I try this:

```
class MessagesViewController: UIViewController { ... }
```

it doesn't prints any error, but when I use this:

```
class MessagesViewController: JSQMessagesViewController { ... }
```

it prints, that:

```
[JSQMessagesInputToolbar preferredDefaultHeight]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd6aa6b5b20
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[JSQMessagesInputToolbar preferredDefaultHeight]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd6aa6b5b20'
```

and I do not know how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like an issue with JSQMessagesViewController and auto layout. Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398312/automatic-preferred-max-layout-width-is-not-available-on-ios-versions-prior-to-8

Comment: no, it did not fix my problem