# Cocoa GUI done with Interface Builder has correct layout on my machine, incorrect on another

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm trying to build a rather simple GUI using xCode/Cocoa. I've designed it in Interface Builder using a storyboard and set the corresponding constraints.

I'm using xCode 7.3.1 on 10.11.6 (El Capitan) ... the deployment target is set to 10.9. On my machine, everything looks fine:

[image]

When I run the application on another machine 10.10.5 (Yosemite), it looks like this:
[image]

I've tried lots of different combinations of vertical and horizontal stack views to organize the elements.. as well as setting some dummy constraints. The result on the Yosemite machine will change slightly, but is never correct/the same.

**UPDATE**: *I've found out that if I don't use neither vertical nor horizontal stack views, the situation gets a lot better. Still doesn't really explain why it can look different on 2 machines*

How is this possible? I thought the .storyboard file is fixed at compile-time?
Any hints you can give me will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this (more of a workaround, actually) by removing all stack views from the storyboard.

Also, I took a closer look at the "Automatic preferred width mode" warning:
[image]

Solved those by following the steps described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867875/649700

I'm still puzzled as to how this is even possible. If stack views are not fully supported or don't behave the same way earlier OS versions, there should at least be warning when I choose "deployment target 10.9"!  Better yet, Xcode should disable the stack views altogether if that's the case.

Hope this helps someone out there.